How to correctly calculate the signal strength loss of a ultrasonic sound?
So i am trying to calculate what is the amplitude of a received signal, if transmitted by a tranducer directly towards the surface of water body with a PVC plate laying underneath. The setup is shown here below.

The initial amplitude of the signal is 5V, and its frequency is 1MHz. When i calculate the strength of the returned signal, after it has been reflected by the plastic(PVC) plate, assumin H2 = 30cm and H1 = 50cm, i get 0.7177V.
The Amplitude after reflection i have calculated with:
$$R=\frac{Z_2-Z1}{Z_2+Z_1}$$
$$I_r=I_i*R^2$$
When i calculate the loss in amplitude as the signal travels through the air and then the water it is almos negligeable having only lost ~2mV when it reaches the bottom of the water. I am quite new in this field, but the small loss in signal strength as it travels through air and water seems wrong. I have used Beer's law to calculate these:$$I=I_0*e^{-\alpha d}$$
With alpha for water and air at 20 degrees being:$$\alpha_{air}=7.5\frac{dB}{s*cm}$$$$\alpha_{water}=0.0022\frac{dB}{s*cm}$$
These numbers i have found on website which i didnt save...
I think the attenuation coefficient relies on the absorption and scattering coefficient for ultrasonic, but i could be mistaken as i am very new in this field.
I read that the attenuation coefficient for air relies on pressure, temperature and humitity but i am unsure how big of an impact they would have on loss and if they are negligeable for a simple setup?
Any pointers on what i am doing wrong or on how i would more preciesly calculate the attenuation coefficent for a medium would be greatly appriciated!

Im not an ultrasound expert, but I find it interesting that $I=I_0\cdot e^{-\alpha d}$ uses dB as a unit, but $e$ as the base. I feel like one should either need to use a base of 10 or convert from dB to nepers.

In my calculations i use a base of 10, but this is just to explain what i have used to calculate the result. Cause i am also in doubt of these values, as it seems hard to find a overview of the attenuation values for air and water at different temperatures.

So i found my mistake, i was doing the calculations wrong as pointed out in dB instead of converting to base of 10 or nepers. I thought i was doing it in base of 10 but was mistaken. After correcting this my results looks more correct with high frequency sounds(>MHz) getting attenuated alot.
